# Are children's toy guns allowed on a British Airways flight as carry-on?

Tags: air-travel, airport-security, hand-luggage, british-airways, firearms

**Are children's toy guns allowed on a BA airplane?**

- One is a water gun and the other one is nerf gun
- They are not replica guns, I am aware that replica guns are almost illegal in the UK.
- Our flight is within the UK
- They are carried by the child himself

I am almost sure they are allowed but when I was a child the security at a Moroccan airport took my shotgun of me and his exact words were "That's not what we agreed on".
However children's toys in the Arab world follow no standards and a plastic bullet from that gun could really hurt.

I assume my child's guns are EU approved as I have bought them from [Toys R Us](http://www.toysrus.co.uk/toys/).

By EU approved I mean the manufacturers follow the EU standards safety-wise and these toys present no threat to the children and the passengers and they can't be used to hijack or sabotage the plane.

Comment: I have no idea why my comment was removed. Deletion-Power-Hybris? So here my question again: Can you clarify what you mean by "EU approved" and put it in relation to the question? Because, e.g. my 30 cm kitchen knives are legal (EU approved?), too.

Comment: I'm confused by the downvotes. It seems like a fairly valid question, their page (as per the answer below) even answers this, and a google search shows others wonder this too.

Comment: @MarkMayo It's because I am the one who asked the question, that's all..

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28764/discussion-on-question-by-inactive-are-childrens-toy-guns-allowed-on-a-british).

Comment: I feel like this question should also be posted in Parenting, but from the perspective of BA. I can only see the items being used to disturb other passengers.

Comment: Anecdotal evidence, but my brother when he was pretty young had toy guns confiscated at airport security.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [British Airways page on liquids, banned and restricted items](http://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/baggage-essentials/liquids-and-restrictions) has a [link to a PDF document detailing the items which cannot be carried as cabin luggage](http://www.britishairways.com/cms/global/pdfs/Security-Prohibited-Items-List.pdf). This document mentions toy guns as being forbidden in carry-on luggage (emhpasis mine):

> #### PASSENGERS AND CABIN BAGGAGE
>
> Without prejudice to applicable safety rules, passengers are not permitted
>   to carry the following articles into security restricted areas or on board an
>   aircraft, on either their person or in cabin baggage:
>
> 1. guns, firearms and other devices that discharge projectiles – devices
>      capable, or appearing capable, of being used to cause serious injury
>      by discharging a projectile, including:
>
>    - firearms of all types, such as pistols, revolvers, rifles, shotguns
>    - **toy guns**, replicas and imitation firearms capable of being mistaken
>        for real weapons

It would therefore be safe to assume that since **both nerf and water gun can be classified as toy guns**, neither will be permitted as cabin luggage on board a British Airways flight.

To be extra sure [you can contact British Airways](http://www.britishairways.com/travel/ctclist/public/en_gb/About_Country=GB) and ask them directly.

Comment: grammatical ambiguity there. Does the clarifier "capable of being mistaken for real weapons" apply to "toy guns, replicas and imitation firearms" or just to "imitation firearms"? If the former, his will be allowed since his toy guns can't be mistaken for real weapons. If the latter, they will not be allowed since all toy guns are banned. I find it more likely it applies to all three, myself.

Comment: @KateGregory I think that it applies only to replicas and imitation firearms. The comma separates the three into two distinct groups.

Comment: if you're an Oxford comma person, yes. But if you're not (I like apples, pears and bananas) then it doesn't. Hence the ambiguity.

Comment: @JoErNanO What you quote here is exactly what's written in the documents I linked to in my response. The 'capable of being mistaken for real weapons' clause clearly apply to the toy guns as well (just as I wrote a couple of hours before you). Assuming anything else would mean that 'toy guns' are generally forbidden, but 'imitation firearms not capable of being mistaken for real weapons' are allowed. That does not make sense at all.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Intuitively that would make sense. However, can you give an example of an `imitation firearms not capable of being mistaken for real weapons`?

Comment: Not all real weapons are black, often I wonder how much real weapons look like toys these days. Security on airlines and railway (Eurostar) are known to reject all toy guns that might look to some like they might be real weapons.

Comment: @JoErNanO Which is just another reason why 'capable of being mistaken for real weapons' obviously also apply to the toy guns.

Comment: (+1) Since this item is part of a list of “devices capable, or appearing capable, of being used to cause serious injury by discharging a projectile” and toy guns usually aren't capable of being used to cause serious injury by discharging a projectile, then they must “appear capable” of doing so to be covered. I don't think there is much ambiguity in this.

Comment: @JoErNanO A [pink, plastic, semi-transparent water-gun](http://www.diytrade.com/china/pd/9190233/plastic_water_gun_toy.html) would not be capable of being mistaken for real weapons for example. By anyone in his right mind that is.

Answer (score 16):

Within the EU, you can bring the water gun, but not the nerf gun in your cabin luggage.

The relevant EU regulation ban 'devices that discharge projectiles', which should cover the nerf gun. The water gun is ok as long as it is obviously a toy gun and is not 'appearing capable, of being used to cause serious injury by discharging a projectile'.

Categories of items banned in cabin luggage are listed in annex part B of [Commission Regulation (EC) No 272/2009](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:02009R0272-20100429&from=EN). You can also find a list of items considered to be covered by the banned categories [here](http://ec.europa.eu/transport/modes/air/security/doc/info_travellers_hand_luggage.pdf).

Comment: And it must not have more than 100mL of water in it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Not quite. If it contains water, then the volume of the gun must be no more than 100ml.

Comment: What kind of monster lets their children have a water gun in any crowded public area?